# Interior point and Minkowski functional

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I want to prove for a convex set that contains zero a point $x$ is interior iff the value of Minkowski functional in that point is strictly less than $1$.
is there anyone to help me.

Comment: Just write the definition of the minkowski functional...

Answer (score 4):

Unless you make additional assumptions on the convex set, this is not true in general. Consider the set $$A = \{ (x,0) \colon x \in [-1,1] \}$$ in $\mathbb R^2$. The corresponding Minkowski functional $p_A$ evaluates to $p_A(x_0) = 1/2$ at $x_0 = (1/2, 0)$, yet $x_0$ is not an interior point of $A$ (since $A$ has no interior).